# Могу ли я для одного пользователя создать несколько сессий?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

У меня есть небольшой web проект. Вопрос такой: когда у меня пользователь делает Log in для него создается сессия в которой лежит объект пользователя, могу ли я создать ещё одну сессию для это-го же юзера? Например чтобы редактировать его услуги(ну сессию в которой будет лежать другой объект, но связанный с этим юзером)?

---

```
    @Override
public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws CommandException, ServletException, IOException {
    if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
        Map<String, String> parsedMap = parseParameter(req);
        ValidationResult validate = validator.validate(parsedMap);

        if (validate.isValid()) {
            String startTime = req.getParameter("startTime");
            String endTime = req.getParameter("endTime");
            String regions = req.getParameter("regions");
            String workPhone = req.getParameter("workingPhone");
            String transport = req.getParameter("transport");
            String capacity = req.getParameter("capacity");
            String aboutMyself = req.getParameter("aboutMyself");
            String courierServiceTransportId = req.getParameter("courierServiceTransportId");

            Transport tr = new Transport();
            tr.setId(Long.parseLong(courierServiceTransportId));
            tr.setTransportName(transport);
            tr.setTransportCapacity(Integer.parseInt(capacity));

            List<Region> regionList = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] split = regions.split(", ");
            for (String s : split) {
                Region region = new Region();
                region.setNameRegion(s);
                regionList.add(region);
            }

            HttpSession session = req.getSession();

            UserDto loginUser = (UserDto) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
            String id = req.getParameter("serviceId");

            CourierDto courierDto = new CourierDto();
            courierDto.setId(Long.parseLong(id));
            courierDto.setUserAccountId(loginUser.getId());
            courierDto.setServiceStatus(CourierServiceStatus.SUBMITTED);
            String[] stTime = startTime.split(":");
            courierDto.setStartTime(LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(stTime[0]), Integer.parseInt(stTime[1]), 0));
            String[] enTime = endTime.split(":");
            courierDto.setEndTime(LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(enTime[0]), Integer.parseInt(enTime[1]), 0));
            courierDto.setMobilePhone(workPhone);
            courierDto.setRegions(regionList);
            courierDto.setTransport(tr);
            courierDto.setAboutMyself(aboutMyself);

            service.editCourierServiceInfo(courierDto);
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/courierServiceList");
        } else {
            req.setAttribute("checkData", true);
            req.setAttribute("courierServiceError", validate.getErrors().get("courierServiceError"));
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/editCourierServicePage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
    } else {
        String courierServiceId = req.getParameter("courierServiceId");
        CourierDto courierServiceById = service.getCourierServiceById(Long.parseLong(courierServiceId));
        System.out.println(courierServiceById);
        StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
        for (Region region : courierServiceById.getRegions()) {
            stringJoiner.add(region.getNameRegion());
        }
        String regions = stringJoiner.toString();
        req.setAttribute("regions", regions);
        req.setAttribute("courierService", courierServiceById);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/editCourierServicePage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }


}
```

И когда юсер пытается редактировать данные, но какие-то поля не валидны, при возврате на стр с редактированием, данные были уже заполнены тем что он ввел при попытке изменить

Comment: А попробовать не пробовали? Конечно же можно. Кто запрещает?

Comment: @And А можно потом удалить именно эту вторую сессию или изменить её?

Comment: А зачем? Что мешает хранить два объекта в рамках одной сессии?

Comment: А если их потом гора будет?)

Comment: И что из этого?

Comment: Ну мб это как-то скажется на производительности, сессия же хранится на сервере.

Comment: А две сессии будут храниться на клиенте?

Comment: Ну как я понимаю сами сессии хранятся на сервере, а у клиента есть только ID к ним, если я не прав можете меня поправить?

Comment: Правильно. Так объясните еще раз - какую выгоду вы ожидаете получить от нескольких сессий по сравнению с одной сессией?

Comment: А можно все таки привести пример кода с которым возникают проблемы? Просто сейчас идет какое-то обсуждение "сферических коней в ваакуме"

Comment: У меня есть страница jsp на которой пользователь может редактировать данные своих услуг, когда он на нее переходят в input полях уже вбиты данные об этой услуге(благодаря сессии).

Comment: Можно, но зачем Вам 2 сессии? О какой производительности идет речь? `HttpSession` является уже мапкой, так и храните свои объекты по разным уровням и ключам... не понимаю вашу логику.

Comment: То есть можно спокойно создавать n количество session для пользователя и не переживать?

Comment: Да но это плохой, а точнее не правильный подход. Это как минимум будет требовать больше ресурсов, о чем вы собственно и переживаете, но я все-же не понимаю, почему вам нужно 2?) Почему бы просто не использовать ключи и коллекции для хранения разной информации?

Comment: Для того чтобы повторно отображать инфу на UI)

Comment: Ну так в контексте сервлета сохраняйте коллекцию с вашими значениями, где: `key => value` - ключ `id` поля `value` значение. В чем проблема? `getServletContext().setAttribute("sessionHashMap",HashMap);` ну а потом просто извлекайте и вставляйте в поля формы...

Comment: Ну или конечно-же: `session.setAttribute("saveHashMap", hashMap);` и будет у вас сохраненная коллекция. Которую достаньте по `saveHashMap` и уже от туда возьмите ключи и значения для формы.

Comment: А чем это getServletContext().setAttribute("sessionHashMap",HashMap); Отличается от просто request.setAttribute()?

Comment: Контекст относится к `ServletConfig`,  а `request` - это уже `HttpServletRequest`, но вам стоит сохранять в сессию `session.setAttribute("saveHashMap", hashMap);`, а потом эту мапку доставать и применять к форме, где ключ - это название поля, а значение его текст.

Comment: @And каким образом, по-вашему, можно создать несколько сессий? Этим занимается контейнер, а не разработчик напрямую.